# Integral of smooth function with compact support is also smooth

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In Ronkin's Теория аналитических функций нескольких переменных he introduces an integral
$$f(z)=-\frac1\pi\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\varphi\left(z+t\mathrm{e}^{-i\theta}\right)\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dt$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $\varphi\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a complex function that is $C^k$ as a function of two real variables, and $\mathrm{supp}\,\varphi$ is compact.
He says the function $\varphi(z+t\mathrm e^{i\theta})$ treated as a function of parameter $z$ is $C^k$ (which again is to be understood as a function of two real variables).
He then says the integral, or the function $f$ is also $C^k(\mathbb{R}^2)$ because the support of $\varphi$ is compact.

I don't understand the latter statement, why is it $C^k(\mathbb{R}^2)$? Where do we need the compactness of $\mathrm{supp}\,\varphi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify the smoothness, you just need to ascertain that it is "ok to differentiate under the integral symbol"; i.e., that doing something like this (if we put $z = x + i y$), for example,
$$
{\partial \over \partial x} f(z) = -{1 \over \pi} \int_{t = 0}^{t = \infty} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 2\pi} \; {\partial \over \partial x} \phi \left(z + e^{-t \theta}\right) \; d\theta \; dt
$$
is legitimate.

Why do we need the compactness of support?  To make sure that the integration over the unbounded domain $0 \leq t < \infty$ converges.  Without this compactness, if we took $\phi$ to be constantly equal to $1$, the double integral would not exist.

Zorich's Математический анализ (Mathematical Analysis) may give a cleaner, more detailed and better paced explanation of differentiation under the integral.

Comment: He uses smoothness to ascertain it's ok to differentiate under the integral sign, so the other way around to what you say (I assume smoothness is equivalent to being able to interchange differentiation and integration? If not, then his proof is missing something.
So, roughly speaking, we need compactness of the support to guarantee that the integral exists (in Lebesque sense, so it's finite) which mean we can differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: Yes.  If the integral diverged, there would be no meaningful function to differentiate.  And if $\phi$ wasn't smooth enough, we may not have been able to commute differentiation and integration.